# Is it true that the US has stepped into foreign conflicts mostly under Democratic presidents?

Tags: united-states, president, armed-conflict, geopolitics, foreign-policy

I recently read about a strange trend: [Since the start of the 20th century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_involving_the_United_States#20th-century_wars), the United States has stepped in or started conflicts involving the direct use of military force mainly under presidents from the [Democratic Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratic_Party_(United_States)).

**Is this trend really present?**

Comment: I don't believe this is a push question, as it makes no judgement as to whether intervening in foreign conflicts is a good thing or a bad thing. It's simply asking whether Democratic presidents are more likely to do so.

Comment: I've just asked about a tendency, nothing more - without blaming it good, or bad. Seems, that downvoters think, that wars are bad, and such tendency deserves a downvote.) And thank for your edits - looks better now

Comment: Where did you read this? Linking to the source in the question would be helpful.

Comment: The answer is very simple - I don't remember.)) I use to read political analytics every day - because I'm interested in politics, an I like it, and one of the articles mentions that tendency. I've gone further and tried to check - and that really seems to be a tendency. But maybe I'm mistaking?

Comment: This leaves out two gulf wars, the US invasion of Grenada and numerous others. This seems a rather disingenuous presentation of the US's foreign involvement.

Comment: @DonHosek Huh?  "George Bush and the Iraq War" is right there.

Comment: @JustMe It also leaves out the invasion of Afghanistan, there's the first Gulf war... The pulling out of "George Bush and the Iraq War" from the list (and allowing two Iraq wars started under two George Bushes) seems very much like an attempt to distort the record.

Comment: Downvoted because the US started NONE of the conflicts listed.  Most were the result of attacks on the US or its allies.  A few, such as Yugoslavia, seem to have been from mostly humanitarian motives.

Comment: you know, you'd get less accusation of push if you actually linked to wherever it is you *recently read about a strange trend* otherwise, it is an incomplete list and it does look a bit fishy.

Comment: @jamesqf "Downvoted because the US started NONE of the conflicts listed." Libya?  UN Security Council Resolution 1973 sure wouldn't have passed without US support.  And the long-term consequences of that action are still being felt - no nation has voluntarily admitted to and given up an illicit WMD program since then.  Gaddafi gave up his WMD program and he wound up dead.  North Korea and Syria kept theirs.  And Syria even used them against their own civilians...

Comment: @F1Krazy: It's not even asking that. It's asking about a correlation, which is confounded by (the entirety of international geopolitics), so you can't draw causal conclusions from it anyway.

Comment: @Just Me: You think the Gaddafi regime didn't have a long history of attacking the US and its allies?

Comment: Frame challenge: constitutionally, Congress decides whether we enter wars, not the president, so assigning blame to a president for wars that were entered into by Congress (i.e. basically every war before the 1990s) is a bit disingenuous.

Comment: @jamesqf : the question is meaningful even without considerations about the motivations of wars. One answer could be "yes, most wars started under democrats, and they were fought against really bad guys".

Comment: Also : Afghanistan 2001 - Republican George W. Bush is missing from the list.

Comment: The question is presented pretty value free, so can we discuss and answer it value free please? If that list was complete, the question wouldn't need to be asked, would it?

Comment: Please clarify whether *"foreign conflicts"* refers solely to conflicts involving the US military using conventional weaponry, or if it may also refer to the US secretly fomenting civil wars via espionage and funding, or may it refer to economic warfare (the results of which can also be devastating) as well.

Comment: @agc, second is widespread and continuous, so, in fact, cannot be included into the list. So, yes, direct use of US military force.

Comment: This question is being discussed [on meta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4530/questions-that-imply-causation-from-correlation-should-be-disallowed).

Comment: @CGCampbell, does "armed conlict with direct US special forces/army involvement" would be enoguh? In present times formulation "declared war" is too hypocritical, especially according to the US

Comment: @CGCampbell, that's not "cherry picking" - that are most known and biggest conflicts, I think. It's strange to include "Somali pirate war 1" and "Somali pirate war 2" in such list.

Comment: Would the formula "armed conlict with direct US special forces/army involvement" be enough? If removing the list of conflicts at all?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Part of the issue with answering this question is defining what counts as a foreign intervention. The Congressional Research Service has published a report entitled *[Instances of Use of United States Armed Forces Abroad, 1798-2020](https://fas.org/sgp/crs/natsec/R42738.pdf)*, which is an attempt to "provide a rough survey of past U.S. military ventures abroad". However, it is questionable whether some of these deployments really count as interventions in foreign conflicts - for example, the list includes entries such as:

> 1904 - Tangiers, Morocco
>
> A squadron demonstrated to force the release of a kidnapped Americans
> Ion Hanford Perdicaris and Cromwell Varley. Marines were landed to
> protect the consul general.
>
> 1922 - Turkey
>
> A landing force was sent ashore with consent of both Greek and
> Turkish authorities to protect American lives and property when the Turkish Nationalists entered
> Smyrna.
>
> 1948 - China
>
> Marines were dispatched to Nanking to protect the American embassy when the city fell to
> Communist troops, and to Shanghai to aid in the protection and evacuation of Americans.

It does, however, note the eleven times in its history that the US has formally declared war, as well as the number of informal declarations of war.

> The instances differ greatly in number of forces, purpose, extent of
> hostilities, and legal authorization. Eleven times in its history, the
> United States has formally declared war against foreign nations. These
> 11 U.S. war declarations encompassed five separate wars: the war with
> Great Britain declared in 1812; the war with Mexico declared in 1846;
> the war with Spain declared in 1898; the First World War, during which
> the United States declared war with Germany and with Austria-Hungary
> during 1917; and World War II, during which the United States declared
> war against Japan, Germany, and Italy in 1941, and against Bulgaria,
> Hungary, and Rumania in 1942.
>
> Some of the instances were extended
> military engagements that might be considered undeclared wars. These
> include the Undeclared Naval War with France from 1798 to 1800; the
> First Barbary War from 1801 to 1805; the Second Barbary War of 1815;
> the Korean War of 1950-1953; the Vietnam War from 1964 to 1973; the
> Persian Gulf War of 1991; global actions against foreign terrorists
> after the September 11, 2001, attacks on the United States; and the
> war with Iraq in 2003. With the exception of the Korean War, all of
> these conflicts received congressional authorization in some form
> short of a formal declaration of war.

If we look at these conflicts, all formal declarations of war since 1900 have come under Democratic presidents - those related to WWI & II, while the informal declarations of war are more mixed; the Korean & Vietnam wars began under Democratic presidents, while the Gulf War, the response to the 9/11 attacks, and the Iraq war all came under Republicans; Bush Sr. & Jr. This would seem to be a fairly even split.

In an optimistic attempt to view this issue in a more data-focused manner, I've looked at the [Militarized Interstate Disputes](https://correlatesofwar.org/data-sets/MIDs) dataset maintained by the Correlates of War Project, which lists information about 'conflicts in which one or more states threaten, display, or use force against one or more other states'. I've narrowed the dataset down to conflicts which involved the US, began after 1900, and in which the hostility level reached a level of '4' - indicating use of force, rather than just a display of force.

Below is a graph of these conflicts, the size of each red or blue dot relating to the fatality level, and the color of each relating to the party of the President. On a purely numerical basis, Republican presidents oversaw 53 of these incidents, while Democratic presidents oversaw 41. However, when we look at the severity of the disputes, those which came under Democratic presidents reached, on average, a higher level of hostility and a higher fatality level.

<sub>Note - 'Interstate' refers to conflicts between two or more sovereign states, not two or more states within the USA.</sub>

[image]

Comment: it would be very nice if the motive of war endeavors was also analised, with respect to the party in power at the time.

Comment: @carlo that seems hard to do objectively. Is there a more narrowly defined aspect of the motives that you think is useful and amenable to objectively measuring?

Comment: How does it change if the it is broken out by who initiated the formal conflict with the USA.  For example Japan attacking Pearl Harbor lead FDR to declare war, but I wouldn't considering this FDR starting the conflict.

Answer (score 14):

This list omits a lot of less known foreign conflicts. Looking at [the list of wars involving the United States on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_involving_the_United_States#20th-century_wars), we find a lot more. Let's start with the second World War, as WWII really marks the start of US military involvement in geopolitics.

- World War II - US engagement started under Franklin D. Roosevelt (Dem)
- Korean War - Harry S. Truman (Dem)
- Laotian Civil War - Lyndon B. Johnson (Dem)
- Lebanon Crisis - Dwight D. Eisenhower (Rep)
- Bay of Pigs Invasion - John F. Kennedy (Dem)
- Vietnam War - Lyndon B. Johnson (Dem)
- Dominican Civil War - Lyndon B. Johnson (Dem)
- Che Guevara's Insurgency in Bolivia - Lyndon B. Johnson (Dem)
- Cambodian Civil War -  Richard Nixon (Rep)
- War in South Zaire - Jimmy Carter (Dem)
- Multinational Intervention in Lebanon - Ronald Reagan (Rep)
- Invasion of Grenada - Ronald Reagan (Rep)
- Various shootouts with Libya in the 1980s - Ronald Reagan (Rep)
- Iran-Iraq War - Ronald Reagan (Rep)
- Invasion of Panama - George H.W. Bush (Rep)
- Gulf War - George H.W. Bush (Rep)
- Somali Civil War Part 1 - George H.W. Bush (Rep)
- Bosnian War - Bill Clinton (Dem)
- Intervention in Haiti - Bill Clinton (Dem)
- Kosovo War - Bill Clinton (Dem)
- Operation Infinite Reach in Afghanistan - Bill Clinton (Dem)
- War in Afghanistan ("War on Terror") - George W. Bush (Rep)
- Iraq War - George W. Bush (Rep)
- Somali Civil War Part 2 - George W. Bush (Rep)
- Operation Ocean Shield (anti-piracy operations in the Indian Ocean) - Barack Obama (Dem)
- International intervention in Libya - Barack Obama (Dem)
- Uganda Civil War  - Barack Obama (Dem)
- Syrian Civil War - Barack Obama (Dem)
- American Intervention in Libya - Barack Obama (Dem)

I left out the following conflicts from the Wikipedia list, because US involvement was either negligible or involved US forces which happened to be on location when someone else started a war:

- Communist insurgency in Thailand
- Simba Rebellion
- Korean DMZ Conflict
- Gulf of Sidra incident
- Yemen Civil War

So if we look at that list, we can see that there were just 2 presidents since World War II which did not start any armed foreign conflicts:

- Gerald Ford (Rep)
- Donald Trump (Rep)

But it would be disingenuous to label any party as the party of warmongering presidents and the other as the party of pacifist presidents. The United States fought a lot of wars under a lot of Presidents of both parties.

Comment: Regarding the recent edit I reverted: The "War in Afghanistan" was not a continuation of Operation Infinite Reach. Infinite Reach was over. The War in Afghanistan was the 2001 US invasion of Afghanistan which removed the Taliban regime.

Comment: @Phillip, great thanks - I've thought about the fact, that those may be some separate things, when posted an edit. It's something new for me - US is there for so long

Comment: Equating the "Somali Civil War Part 2" with WW2 or the Vietnam war is kind of ridiculous. -1.

Comment: @YellowBadger I tried to provide a picture which is as complete as possible. How and where exactly would you suggest to draw the line between noteworthy and not-noteworthy wars?

Comment: @Philip I can appreciate bringing attention to lesser wars but some of those listed could hardly be called "wars" at all (Bay of Pigs invasion??) and others seem so obscure and serve only to dilute the significance of other wars. Also seems rather arbitrary to start listing small-scale conflicts starting with WW2 as the USA has had many international conflicts before then (Spanish-American war, Mexican-American war, WW1, war of Independence etc).

Comment: @YellowBadger So what would you suggest I should do? Regarding the starting date: Well, we got to start *somewhere*. If we go further back, then the party affiliations are no longer meaningful. And WWII really marks the point where the US became a global superpower. Regarding the bay of pigs invasion: It might  have been a rather small operation, but its was still very politically significant.

Comment: @YellowBadger: well, the premise of the question, i.e. "conflict counting" is ridiculous.

Comment: A lot of these lists also tend to ignore that U.S. involvement in Vietnam started with Eisenhower sending in military advisors in 1955, with American deaths starting in 1959.

Comment: Re Us Presidents who didn't start armed conflicts, few of those were STARTED by the US.  Offhand the only one I can think of was the totally unwarranted military action in Panama.  The rest were either the US responding to attacks on itself or its allies, or global humanitarian interventions.

Comment: The way you count makes Chomsky grin: East Timor without Ford as little helper? And also Carter setting the stage for Rambo III "and the brave Mujahideen"? It's also very very questionable to label WW2 as "start of". That was *a lot* earlier. You do not remember the Maine and neglect that without US WWI would have  just stopped in 1916. As such, it seems Monroe doctrine or Perry in Japan would be better points of departure? Or the Marine anthem: "to the shores of Tripoli"? So Barbary Wars, or even the rebellious illegal insurgency of the disloyal slave-owning tax-dodgers a few years earlier?

Comment: "as WWII really marks the start of US military involvement in geopolitics"  Every single resident of Spain, Cuba, and the Philippines would disagree with that.  Along with everyone living in Panama and Ecuador.  And a high percentage of Mexicans.  Germans and French, too.

Answer (score 1):

That list is really misleading -- look at the reasons the US entered the war instead of just looking at the party of the person in office.

It should also be noted that the president doesn't have the power to take us to war without the approval of congress.

[WW1](https://www.rochester.edu/newscenter/looking-back-100-years-u-s-enters-world-war-i-on-april-6-1917/#:%7E:text=The%20U.S.%20entered%20World%20War,American%20entry%20into%20the%20war.): Germany was sinking US merchant ships.

WW2: Pearl Harbor attacked by Japan.

[Korean](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zqqd6yc/revision/2#:%7E:text=The%20United%20States%20believed%20it,elsewhere%20made%20America%20more%20determined.): Protecting South Korea from being taken over by North Korea.

[Vietnam](https://www.history.com/topics/vietnam-war/vietnam-war-history): Protecting South Vietnam from being taken over by North Vietnam.

The last two wars listed were to counter the moves by the Soviet Union attempting to increase its overall power.

Comment: "It should also be noted that the last two wars I listed where to counter the moves by the soviet union attempting to spread Communism ans increase its overall power at our detriment." - this is exactly the problem with the US. If something undermines US power projection, then the US intervenes - regardless of the effect it has on the rest of the world.

Comment: I downvoted because this answers a slightly different question as compared to the question that is being asked - in particular it implies that the US should have intervened, which isn't something that's in the question.

Comment: @Allure Are you saying the cause of the war doesn't matter at all? That it is more important about what party the president is than if we were forced into the ware by being attacked? It may not answer the question exactly but it is also important to know why we went to war intstead of just asking what the party of the president is.

Comment: @epiliam Are you saying that a country should sit by and do nothing while another country is attacked and losing their freedoms? That it is is okay for an oppressive government to take over and control the people by force?

Comment: @JoeW A rule of exams is to answer the question that's being asked, not the question you think is asked, and "Is it true that the US has stepped into foreign conflicts mostly under Democratic presidents?" is a yes/no question. It's either true or untrue. Your answer doesn't deal with that, it deals with the question "is it morally justified for the US to intervene?" or some other similar question.

Comment: @Allure This isn't an exam so thankfully that doesn't apply here and I never stated that I thought that was the question being asked. I will point out again that for my first two examples it was the United States being attacked by another country. In cases like that does it matter what party the president belongs to? Shouldn't you count it differently if war is declared based on the country being attacked? Or its allies being attacked and calling for aid? Or someone starting a war for other reasons? My answer isn't asking if it was morally justified but if the party of the president matters.

Comment: @Allure Afterall for WW1 and WW2 do you think the US would not have gone to war if it was a Republican in office? Or does it matter that the political parties have shifted around drastically since those two wars? In the end, isn't the justifications for going to war more important than the political party of the president? Especially considering that congress is also required to approve going to war?

Comment: @JoeW if you want to debate whether it is morally justified or whatever, you should do it in a different question. I won't be drawn off topic. As I wrote, the OP is a yes/no question. You are imposing your interpretation on it, an interpretation that might not align with what the OP intends. Hence the downvote.

Comment: @Allure Are you still trying to claim that it is more important that a Democrat called us to WW1 and WW2 (which was also approved by the Senate in unanimous votes) than the reasons they made their decisions? Or the fact that large numbers of the Democrat party left for the Republican party during the civil rights era shifting the stance of both parties? This isn't trying to justify all the wars just ask to also consider the reason. Also, it should be pointed out the US has not declared war since 1941 and everything since then has been armed conflicts.

Comment: @JoeW no, I'm saying it's *irrelevant* to *this question*. If you don't know what "irrelevant" means, please search it up in a dictionary. I won't be responding anymore.

Comment: @Allure Here I thought it was important to consider the difference between going to war because a country is attacked by another country and trying to protect oil fields (as the accusations of the gulf wars claim) for big oil. I mean I would think that there is a big difference between WW2 and the Gulf war for example

Comment: @JoeW my comment has nothing to do with that. My comment is also independent of my opinions on the particular wars named. I am saying that if something undermines US ability to project global power, they will take any means necessary to amend that with little to no regards for anything else.

Comment: @CGCampbell How is the Soviet Union in any way related to my comments?

Comment: @epiliam well it does matter as it is the reason the US did take those actions

Comment: I was not commenting on particular actions, I was commenting on the US attitude towards foreign policy. Did I not already clarify that? Besides - the USSR has been dissolved for 30 years.

Comment: @epiliam and my examples are things that happened in direct response to USSR (and others) interfering in another country. Not as actions that the US took on their own

Comment: Okay. I am not denying that my comment was off topic, as it had nothing to do with the wars named. I was commenting on your remark along the lines of "we did this because not doing so was at our detriment". I commented because I felt this typified US foreign policy of the past fifty years and is a huge issue for the world.